# Python module error

Tags: python, module, anaconda

Hi I am new to Python I want to use an already developed tool/code and I have a problem with the modules used.
I installed Spider with Anaconda version of Python

I am trying to run below code,
https://code.google.com/p/quantandfinancial/source/browse/trunk/example_black_litterman.py

if I understood the code correctly it is referencing the below custom module https://code.google.com/p/quantandfinancial/source/browse/trunk/structures/quote.py?r=25

I stored the two parts of the code in `C:\Users\Michal\Documents\Python Scripts` and Python is installed in `C:\Anaconda3`, when I run the code I get an error

```
File "C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Python Scripts/Black-Litterman.py", line 4, in <module>
    from structures.quote import QuoteSeries
ImportError: No module named 'structures'
```

Please help how can I get this code running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pip install structures** worked for me from normal windows cmd

> C:\Users\user>pip install structures

You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version **7.1.2** is available.
You should consider upgrading via the `'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'` command.

```
> Collecting structures   
> Downloading structures-2.0.2.tar.bz2
> Installing collected packages: structures   
> Running setup.py install for structures 
> Successfully installed structures-2.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
pip install structures
```

Best idea is probably to first [make a `conda` environment](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html), then you can manage all the packages you need in there.

Comment: is the "structures" a package? I thought it was just a module which is referenced from the main code and I need to place it somewhere in one of python's folders. Where should I run the fist command? I tried  in the console but I get "Invalid syntax" error

Comment: Yes, [`structures`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/structures) is a package. Run `pip` on the command line (that is, not in the Python interpreter).

Comment: It doesn't get installed, syntax error:    Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Oct 20 2015, 07:26:33) [MSC v.1 900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. >>> pip install structures File "<stdin>", line 1 pip install structures ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: still the same, "invalid syntax", I closed spider, typed  exit() on the command (C:\Anaconda3\python.exe)  and then tried the "pip install structures"   the reference in the main code is ("4 from structures.quote import QuoteSeries") should the name of the package different? how about the location of the file, is the "Python Scripts" in my Documents fine? 
>>> pip install structures
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install structures
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>